# C#: Extending from more than 1 class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, dependency-properties, mvvm-foundation

Suppose I have a ViewModel `TabViewModel` that Extends `ObservableObject` the class for ViewModels in the MVVM Foundation Framework. Then I also have a `EditorTabViewModel` that extends `TabViewModel`, Now I need to extend `DependencyObject` to implement DependencyProperties. I cannot extend more than 1 class. How might I implement this? I could have an "intermediate" class like ...

```
TabViewModel : ObservableObject

EditorTabViewModel : TabViewModel

DependentEditorTabViewModel : DependencyObject
```

but thats 1 extra unnecessary class. Any better way to do this?

**UPDATE**

Ops actually I cant do the above. `DependentEditorTabViewModel` still need to extend EditorTabViewModel ... apart from `DependencyObject`

Answer (score 2):

C# does not support [Multiple Inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance). Your best bet is to use Interfaces, rather than parent classes.

Even if you don't have the option of using interfaces (maybe you don't have access to the code), it's generally better to [prefer composition over inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance). Do you really need to *inherit* both of these classes, or can you *compose* with them instead?

Comment: In my above scenario, how could I implement composition over inheritance? I read about that b4 but in this case, maybe my mind is not working well :)

Comment: @jiewmeng: I'm afraid I don't know anything about the MVVM Foundation Framework, so I can't help with the details. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Its not an extra class if you're accomplishing what you need.  Here is how you would go about that:

```
DependentEditorTabViewModel : DependencyObject

TabViewModel : DependentEditorTabViewModel
```

Comment: I think I made a similar mistake ... apart from `DependencyObject`, I still need to extend `ObservableObject`. In other words, I need the resultant class to extend mainly `DependencyObject`, `ObservableObject`.

Comment: Ok.  Unfortunately, c# doesn't support multiple inheritance.  Look into implementing an interface instead.